# Why does this work the way it does (rstrip)

Tags: python, bioinformatics, strip, biopython

I have a code that works properly but I don't understand it. Why does `buf[1:]` print out only `Rosalind_4402` without the DNA afterwards.
FASTA =

```
>Rosalind_4402
GCAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTGGGATTCGGATCGGCGCCCCGAGAGGATTCTTTCAGCTGTAA
GAATTTATCCTCGATCGGGCTATAAAACCTACGCATATCTGCTAGCTGAGGGGCTATCTT
```

```
with open("rosalind_gc.txt") as FASTA:
    buf = FASTA.readline().rstrip()
    print(buf)
    while buf:
        seq_name, seq = buf[1:], ''
        print(seq_name)
        buf = FASTA.readline().rstrip()
        while not buf.startswith('>') and buf:
            seq = seq + buf
            buf = FASTA.readline().rstrip()
        print(seq)
```

Comment: Would you check your formatting? Worth noting, `buf[1:]` appears nowhere in your code.

Comment: `readline()` only reads one line at a time...

Comment: Makes sense so is the line that is stripped removed from the FASTA?

Comment: try buf = FASTA.readlines()

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you try to get one or more fasta sequences from a file whether given by a name list of BLAST sequences or just all sequences. With the below script you can perform both type of actions.

The last line in the file might be a fasta sequence, an end-of-line character or something else. The output to buffer would halt midway if not covered. Therefor you screen if end-of-line character or total lines in the fasta file.

Older versions of fastafiles were irregular so sometimes there were multiple '\n' newline characters or none at all. Both are dealt with using the lock.

Enjoy.

```py
def myseq(seq_file, seq_list=[]):
    # if sequence identifier list (seq_list) is zero then all sequences are returned; if a list is given the matched IDs return seq.
    buf = FASTA.readlines()
    
    lines = len(buf)
    count = 0
    
    lock = False
    identifier = ''
    string = ''
    result = []
    
    for item in buf:
        print(f'lock : {lock}, item {item}.')
                   
        if (item[0] == '>') and (lock == False):
            identifier = item.rstrip()
            
            # selection based on sequence name in list or empty list to get them all.
            if seq_list != []:
                for seq_name in seq_list:
                    if identifier == seq_name:
                        lock = True
            else:
                lock = True
        
        elif lock and (item[0] in ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'U']):
            string += item.rstrip()
            
        count += 1 # count line positions in list.
        
        if lock and (item == '\n') or (count == lines):
            
            result.append((identifier, string))
            identifier = ''
            string = ''
            lock = False
                
    return result

with open('X:\Test\fasta.txt', encoding = 'utf-8') as FASTA:
#    print(FASTA.readlines())
    buf = myseq(FASTA)
    print(buf)
```

Output from `print(FASTA.readlines())`:

```
['\n', '>Rosalind_4402\n', 'GCAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTGGGATTCGGATCGGCGCCCCGAGAGGATTCTTTCAGCTGTAA\n', 'GAATTTATCCTCGATCGGGCTATAAAACCTACGCATATCTGCTAGCTGAGGGGCTATCTT\n', '\n', '>Rosalind_4403\n', 'GCAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTGGGATTCGGATCGGCGCCCCGAGAGGATTCTTTCAGCTGTAA\n', 'GAATTTATCCTCGATCGGGCTATAAAACCTACGCATATCTGCTAGCTGAGGGGCTATCTT']
```